# ASP.net Core - JsonProperty NullValueHandling.Ignore not working on nullable type

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, openapi, swashbuckle

I have created a model for errors returned from my API.  It goes as follows:

```cs
public class ApiErrorMessage
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Field { get; }

    [JsonProperty("property_name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int? ErrorCode { get; } = null;

    public string Message { get; }

    internal ApiErrorMessage() { }

    public ApiErrorMessage(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }

    public ApiErrorMessage(string field, string message)
    {
        Field = field != string.Empty ? field : null;
        Message = message;
    }

    public ApiErrorMessage(string field, string message, int? errorCode)
    {
        Field = field != string.Empty ? field : null;
        ErrorCode = errorCode.HasValue ? errorCode : null;
        Message = message;
    }
}
```

You can see two properties are marked as ignore if null.  If I set the field as null and return, the object is ignored from the json and not returned.

[image]

However, leaving the nullable type (error code) as null still returns a "null" property.

[image]

Can anyone advise on how to get property to be ignored?  I dont want to return a string - just an integer.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: Does removing default `null` value from `ErrorCode` help?

Comment: No - I actually added that in to try to confirm that it was actually null and that it was being ignored anyway

Comment: have you tried `NullValueHandling.Include`?

Comment: `JsonProperty` is a Json.NET attribute, but if you're using ASP.NET Core 3.0+, you're probably using `System.Text.Json`, which doesn't recognise this attribute, or even have an alternative right now. If you need this level of control, you'll likely be better of [switching back to Json.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-newtonsoftjson-in-an-aspnet-core-30-mvc-project).

Comment: I am infact using .net Core 3.1